# Remove Smart Quotes, Long Hyphens, Ellipsis for web use

Tags: html, email, formatting

I build a lot of email templates and often the content is provided to me in a Word document.

The issue I have is Word formats quotes into the curly "smart quotes" (“”) and dashes into long hyphens (—) and three periods into ellipsis (…).

If you leave these characters in the code they show up as weird symbols with certain email clients. So, what I have been doing is a find and replace but it is a bit tedious.

Is there anyway to convert a document for all of these characters instead of doing a find and replace one by one.

I use Sublime Text 3 for my text editor when developing emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a very exciting way to do it, but it can work.

Open up http://phpfiddle.org/ and paste the code below. Then replace the block of text that I've used as an example with your own text between the **<<< EOT** and **EOT;** tags.

```
$data = <<< EOT
The issue I have is Word formats quotes into
the curly "smart quotes" (“”) and dashes
into long hyphens (—) and three periods into ellipsis (…).
EOT;
echo '<pre>';
echo str_replace(
        ['…', '—', '“', '”'],
        ['...', '-', '"', '"'],
        $data
    );
echo '</pre>';
```

If you need to add extra character replacements to the list, do so as I have done in the square brackets. The first set is what you're looking to replace, the second is what you're replacing it with.

Comment: This totally works! Next step I will have to create a form so I can drop the Code in a textarea and the pass it through this php and output the clean stuff. Thank you for your help!